# Filter Http Request Using PHP Regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

This is a Http Request i made from a C/C++ Application

```
POST /login.php HTTP/1.1
Host: www.copyscape.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:53.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/53.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: http://www.copyscape.com/login.php
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 74
Cookie: ck=BXLD2UDMUA88KWGC0GK8WCGOC; PHPSESSID=8cup5f02hbetnbfbbv9vug37q0
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1

login_username=jeezman88%40vfxm.mail.com.com&login_password=(Passw0rd)&log_in=Log+inÿÿÿ7—R
```

Now i have a challenge, i want to filter the results using php regex, how do i go about this. Like suppose i want to filter to get the Referer how i go about this using the regex function in PHP. And pls I am very new to stuff like this

Comment: ... is your question about the filter handling or about the regex?

Comment: @Stefan, about the filter handling. I want to Filter the Referer and say the form input variables.

Comment: @Stefan, was thinking of using preg_match()

Comment: @chris85, Not really , i want to Filter to get few parameters , thats all...

Comment: @chris85, could you give a full snippet on how to get Referer and post data

Comment: @chris85, first thing you sent over was headers, the c++ application i made was able to get that. Now getting and filtering only the Referer and the post data with the ampersand sign ... is what i want to know. Snippet

Comment: @RealMary Take a look at answer, if you have questions post there.

Comment: thanks that solved the worry i have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```
preg_match('/(?m)^Referer:\h*(.*)$/', $string, $match);
```

should do it. That looks at each line and once a `Referer:` is found it returns the full line. The first capture group is the value.

PHP Demo: https://eval.in/788933

Regex demo: https://regex101.com/r/74a1as/1/